# installing grub and a working kernel over an old and broken debian system

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, system-installation, grub2

I have an old debian system, which I always have been able to upgrade over the years. I had installed an old kernel, compiled by me from sources.

After my last dist-upgrade (using testing distribution), I had a kernel panic at boot. My old kernel and my new libc are not able to work together anymore (I presume).

Even device names are changed: with my latest working kernel, I had `/dev/hda` and `/dev/hdb`, now those devices are recognized as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.

Additionaly, two partitions (`/dev/hda2` and `/dev/hdb2`) were joined in a raid array, which name was `/dev/md0` (mounted as root), and now is `/dev/md127`. Partition `/dev/hda1` was mounted as `/boot`, and `/dev/hdb1` was the swap partition.

I used lilo as boot manager.

Now that everything is broken, I tried to use debian rescue mode, without success. I removed lilo and installed grub2, still nothing works.

So I decided to install a new minimal debian system in the old swap partition (`/dev/hdb1`, now `/dev/sdb1`) and, from there, I tried to rescue the system.

Still nothing: I can't install a working kernel (this time a precompiled one) in the old partitions. I tried to rebuild my old raid array, mount my boot partition, chroot-ed ant apt-get installed a new kernel: grub is not able to see nothing.

I don't know what else I could try...

Comment: Wow, reading this I had to keep checking the date on the question several times! hda -> sda is an expected change, I'd guess about 5 years ago now. The array name change is weird, but not really a huge deal to fix (/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf should do it, also on initramfs). But... what is the current problem you're trying to fix? I'm having a hard time finding the actual question here.

Comment: I cannot install a working kernel (and, yes, this system has been upgraded since... uhm, woody?)

Comment: When you try to install a working kernel, what errors are you getting? What command are you using? Hard to troubleshoot without that... Also, if its a panic, please include the panic messages --- a photo of the screen taken with a smartphone (etc.) is fine.

Comment: chroot + apt-get install kernel. I am missing something, I have read somwhere about "bind mounting" some partitions, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Once you chroot, you need to mount /boot, /proc, and /sys (A bind mount is simple: `mount --bind /sys /chroot/sys`). Still need that error message. You run `apt-get install linux-image-686` or whatever, and surely it gives some errors.

Comment: Do I have to bind mount before chrooting? (I will write the error message after I have tried to reinstall the kernel with the bind mount)

Comment: The bind mount is done from outside the chroot. Whether that's before you run chroot or in a different terminal doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, it worked, after a bind mount! (Now I have a segmentation violation when I start transmission-daemon, but this is another issue)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please take the mess of comments, edit them together into a coherent answer, and post it. Maybe it'll help someone who stumbles across it on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As derobert pointed out, `hda -> sda` is an expected change since a long time.

The raid array name change was weird, but it resolved itself in the end.

I tried to boot from a live cd distribution, mount the raid array, mount the boot partition, then `apt-get install` the new kernel. This procedure produced an error because I didn't know that I should have mounted `/boot`, `/proc` and `/sys`.

So the exact procedure is:

- boot from a live distribution (debian CD 1 in rescue mode is ok)
- mount the root partition (in /chroot, for example) and, eventually,
  the boot partition, if different from root)
- bind mount the special devices:

  - `mount --bind /sys /chroot/sys`
  - `mount --bind /proc /chroot/proc`
  - `mount --bind /dev /chroot/dev`
- chroot to the root partition
- install the new kernel
- reboot

Answer (score 1):

the new ATA driver in the kernel use /dev/sda, the old drivers are still supported but you will have to edit your kernel by chrooting into you system using a livecd.

```
Device drivers --->
 <*> ATA/ATAPI/MFM/TLL support (deprecated)
 <*> Serial ATA and Parallel ATA drivers --->
```

For chrooting I always use the [gentoo minimal installation cd](ftp://de-mirror.org/gentoo/releases/x86/current-iso/install-x86-minimal-20140722.iso) and how to chroot into your system you can read in [the gentoo handbook](https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?full=1), it should also work with your system. Probably there is an other way for debian users, but this way should work for you two.

I hope this the solution for your problem.